# Dual Booting HP Pavilion G6

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, hp-pavilion

I'm a Windows 8 user. I was wondering if there's any way to dual boot my HP pavilion G6 2237ez with Windows 8 and Ubuntu. I just wanted to try Ubuntu and see for myself what's so special about Ubuntu. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You Can, in fact, create a boot disk, called a LiveCD, and run Ubuntu without even installing it on your machine.  This will allow you to test the waters without making the commitment to installing a new OS.  Another option is to boot from a flash drive.

And Yes, you CAN dual boot both OS's.

Just follow the Download and Burning instructions on http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Hope this helps, and Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

if you have already installed two operating systems.

1. Pressing power buttun without other action,you will start win8
2. After you Press power buttun,you immediately click “F9” that you can come into StratMune select "Hard drive boot"

you will Start Ubuntu

Try it. Maybe useful.